# how to change button into <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and I want to change this with `<a>` tag

```
<button type="submit" id='submit_form' name="submit_details" onclick=" $(window).unbind('load');" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
```

I have this code to change:

```
 <a href="#"    style="float:left ;background-color:#26a69a ;color:white ">Submit </a>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have to respect a template that uses  the ` <a href ..`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form_id').submit()">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use jQuery's `$.replaceWith` method? Once you change the button to an anchor, your event will be useless. Is your submit button supposed to redirect?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit_form').replaceWith($('<a>', {
    text : 'Submit',
    href : '#',
    css : {
      float: 'left',
      backgroundColor: '#26a69a',
      color: 'white'
    }}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="submit_form"
        name="submit_details" class="btn btn-primary"
        onclick="$(window).unbind('load');">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
<input type="button" value="google.com" 
  onClick="javascript:location.href = 'http://google.com';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give any id you want to the `<a>` tag. Then write this code and add before the  tag:

```
<script>
   function clickButton(){
     javascript:location.href = 'http://google.com';
   }
   document.getElementById("your_id").addEventListener("click",clickButton,false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the button action, add it via the `onclick` event

```
<a onclick="this.closest('form').submit()" href="#" style="float:left ;background-color:#26a69a ;color:white ">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly? If you want an `<a>` tag to react as button:

```
<a href="#" id="myId">my link</a>
<script>
   var link = document.getElementById('myId');
   link.addEventListener('click', function(){
      // rest of the code
   }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this out:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" class="col-md-7">
   <span class="submit_form" id="submit_form">
    <a class="submit_form" href="">
    </a>
   </span>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Then you can add required href in js for this `<a>` click based on id or name.

Try this one too :

```
<input id="submit_form" type="submit" name="submit_form" value="SUBMIT" class="submit_form" onclick="document.getElementById('form_id').submit()">
```

Comment: `<h:panelGroup>` ?

Comment: <h:panelGroup>is similar to<div>. <h:panelGroup> is jsf. You can use <div> tag